# Wrap email message in invokable method processbuilder

Tags: apex, email, process-builder

I have created and email message which runs perfectly from the anonymous window.

When I try to place it in

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Send an email from apex class'
 description='sends an email')  public static void sendEmailFunction(){

 }
```

I did not receive the email anymore but I cant find any errors in the log. How do I set the code correctly in an **@InvocableMethod**?

**Code:**

```
    public class SendemailController {


    @InvocableMethod(label='Send an email from apex class' description='sends an email')




public static void  sendEmailFunction(List<ID> LeadId) { 

/**name[0] = '00Q0Y000003iRelUAE';
String LeadId= name[0];  **/

Lead getEmail = [SELECT Id, Email_Klant__c FROM Lead WHERE id =: LeadId];
   if(getEmail.Email_Klant__c != null) {
     String toaddress = getEmail.Email_Klant__c;
       system.debug(getEmail);

List<id> ids = new List<id>();
for(Lead curr:[Select (select Id from signrequest__SignRequests__r) from Lead WHERE Lead.Id=:LeadId]){
  for(signrequest__SignRequest__c ss : curr.signrequest__SignRequests__r){
     ids.add(ss.id);  
  }
}
system.debug('ids'+ ids);

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo(toaddress);
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Name');
mail.setSubject('Testing email through apex');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(true);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear tester, here are the attachments. This mail is sent trough apex');


List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();        
 for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId IN :ids AND (NOT Name LIKE '%log.pdf')]){
   Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
   efa.setFileName(a.Name);
   efa.setBody(a.Body);
   fileAttachments.add(efa);
 }        
system.debug('fileAttachments'+ fileAttachments);

mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });  

}       

    }
}
```

`

[image]

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @nightcrawler as I wrote:  I do not receive the email anymore but I cant find any errors in the log.

Comment: Are you using a developer/trial org?

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty Yes from Dev my send email is on because when I run tis from the anonymous window I do receive te mail

Comment: see here "your org can send single emails to a maximum of 15 email addresses per day."  you may reached the limit try in another box or tomorrow. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I tried it from the anonymous window and still got the email So I didnt pass the ammount I Gues I will Update te Code the way I am Using I now with an image of my Processbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might bump into this. The code was working except signrequest does not make te difference between production and sandbox. Al request wil remain linked to production so processbuilder in sandbox does not register any changes to records.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic `Email Action` for use with Process Builder:

```
global class EmailAction {

@InvocableMethod(label='Send Email')
global static List<EmailActionResult> sendEmails(List<EmailActionRequest> requests) {

    List<EmailActionResult> results = new List<EmailActionResult>();

    for(EmailActionRequest request : requests){
        results.add(sendEmail(request));
    }

    return results;
}

public static EmailActionResult sendEmail(EmailActionRequest request) {

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    mail.setSubject(request.subject);
    mail.setBccAddresses(request.getBccAddresses()); 
    mail.setCcAddresses(request.getCcAddresses());
    mail.setTemplateId(request.emailTemplateId);
    mail.setHtmlBody(request.htmlBody);
    mail.setPlainTextBody(request.plainTextBody);
    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(request.orgWideEmailAddressId);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName(request.displayName);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(request.targetObjectId); // Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId
    mail.setWhatId(request.whatId);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(request.saveAsActivity);
    mail.setOptOutPolicy('FILTER');

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    messages.add(mail);

    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

    EmailActionResult emailActionResult = new EmailActionResult();

    for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result :results) {                

        if(result.IsSuccess()) {

            emailActionResult.isSuccess = true;

        } else {

            emailActionResult.isSuccess = false;
            Messaging.SendEmailError[] errors = result.getErrors(); 

            if (errors.size() > 0 ){

                emailActionResult.errorMessage = errors[0].getMessage();
                System.debug('EmailAction error: ' + errors[0].getMessage()); 

            }
        }
    } 

    return emailActionResult;
}

global class EmailActionResult {

    @InvocableVariable
    global Boolean isSuccess;

    @InvocableVariable
    global String errorMessage;

}

global class EmailActionRequest {

    private List<String> bccAddresses;
    private List<String> ccAddresses;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global Id emailTemplateId;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global String subject;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global String htmlBody;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global String plainTextBody;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global String ccAddress;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global String bccAddress;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global Id orgWideEmailAddressId;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global String displayName;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global Id targetObjectId;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global Id whatId;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    global Boolean saveAsActivity;

    public EmailActionRequest() {
        ccAddresses = new List<String>();
        bccAddresses = new List<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getCcAddresses(){

        if (ccAddresses != null){
            ccAddresses.add(ccAddress);    
        }

        return ccAddresses;
    }

    public List<String> getBccAddresses(){

        if (bccAddress != null){
            bccAddresses.add(bccAddress);    
        }

        return bccAddresses;
    }

}
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class EmailActionTests {

@isTest
static void sendEmails_Success(){

    // arrange
    Contact target = new Contact();
    target.FirstName = 'Dee';
    target.LastName = 'Licious';
    target.email = 'dee@example.com';

    insert target;

    Account what = new Account();
    what.Name = 'Ghostbusters';

    insert what;

    EmailAction.EmailActionRequest request = new EmailAction.EmailActionRequest();
    request.bccAddress = 'bcc@example.com';
    request.ccAddress = 'cc@example.com';
    request.displayName = 'Acme Inc';
    request.saveAsActivity = true;
    request.subject = 'Test Subject';
    request.targetObjectId = target.Id;
    request.whatId = what.Id;
    request.plainTextBody = 'Hello World';
    request.htmlBody = '<b>Hello World</b>';

    List<EmailAction.EmailActionRequest> requests = new List<EmailAction.EmailActionRequest>();
    requests.add(request);

    // act
    List<EmailAction.EmailActionResult> results = EmailAction.sendEmails(requests);

    // assert
    System.assertEquals(1, results.size());
    System.assertEquals(true, results[0].isSuccess);
}

}
```